# jasper How to use parameter as argument in a scriplet expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this parameter expression:

```
<parameter name="RECEIVE_DATE_TO" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[com.www.xxx.DateFactory.getJavaDate("today")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

I added a parameter to define the actual argument to my class "DateFactory", like this:

```
<parameter name="RECEIVE_DATE_FROM_FLAG" class="java.lang.String" >
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["YESTERDAY"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

So I wanted to pass the parameter as argument to my DateFactory method, like this:

```
<parameter name="RECEIVE_DATE_FROM" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[com.www.xxxx.DateFactory.getJavaDate($P{RECEIVE_DATE_FROM_FLAG})]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

However the parameter $P{RECEIVE_DATE_FROM_FLAG} is not being passed to "NOW" or "YESTEDAY", it remains as "$P{RECEIVE_DATE_FROM_FLAG}" literally.

How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: i m not sure if paramater can be pass in other paramater in same report. Have u tried DateFactory method in textfieldexpression or fieldexpression?

Comment: yes, that's my question :S